# Yii - call an action method from another action method

Tags: php, yii

Title may be confusing, but here's explanation with code.

Based on some conditions, 
I may call `actionContact` even if user has called `actionIndex`.

**Solution:1**

```
 public function actionIndex()
    { 
        $a = 5;
        if($a == 5){


$this->actionContact();
        }
        else{
            $this->render('index');
        }
    }

    public function actionContact()
    {
        // Some codes
        $this->render('contact');
    }
```

**Solution:2**

```
public function actionIndex()
        { 
            $a = 5;
            if($a == 5){


// Repeat code from actionContact method
            $this->render('contact');
        }
        else{
            $this->render('index');
        }
    }
```

**Solution:3** I can redirect to contact url.

I think, solution 1 works fine for me and I would prefer that. 
But since I am new to yii, I would like to know, if its the way to go ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Repeat code" is very rarely the correct answer. Redirects involve additional overhead, and in my opinion they should mostly be used in response to POST actions, not like this. In this case I would go with solution 1.

Comment: I agree, but is this the standard way or there are other options ?

Answer (score 9):

If its not problem, you could use **forward**

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#forward-detail

```
public function actionIndex()
{ 
    $a = 5;
    if($a == 5){
        // Forward user to action "contact"
        $this->forward('contact'); 
    }
    else{
        $this->render('index');
    }
}

public function actionContact()
{
    // Some codes
    $this->render('contact');
}
```

Comment: I guess, this is the standard way. If I am right, I can forward request to action method of another controller too. Am I right ?. I have already mark other question as answer, so +1.

Comment: Yes, its yii-way :) but i found hard to give it custom params, but for your problem it's ok.

Comment: sorry, didn't answer your question. Yes, you can forward it to another  controller action :)

Comment: i am trying very same, but i cant forward it to a controller which works on PUT verb

Comment: I'm not sure but I think `forward` can't change original request. So you need to send `PUT` at the begining OR instead of forward make `curl` call that sends `PUT` request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257295/send-put-request-with-php-curl

Answer (score 3):

You could use a fourth option, which is refactoring the part that is common to index and contact actions into a third method:

```
public function common() {
    // ...
}

public function actionIndex() {
    // ... call $this->common()
}

public function actionContact() {
    // ... call $this->common()
}
```

The best option depends on your particular case, though. For example, when you decide you have to call a different action, do you want to render its view, too?

Comment: So, methods inside controller are not 'special'. They are just methods with specific names based on user action ?

Comment: if they start with 'action' they are special. in that you can call them via a url. otherwise you can have any old method name, and you can't call it from a url

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, No, I am thinking whether any variable is available in scope of those special methods (and only to those) whose name starts with 'action'

Comment: The "action" prefix is just a marker; from the PHP perspective they are just normal instance methods with standard scoping rules.