# Send PUT request with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to communicate with a web service who's waiting first a token in each request.
There is my problem, the web service is waiting the token throught `file_get_contenst(php://input)`.

I didn't find a way to send cURL request trought this method (sending raw data/put data instead of Post).
Could some one guides me ?

I tried something like :

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:256000', 'w');
fwrite($fp, TOKEN);
fseek($fp, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp); // file pointer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($json));
```

Answer (score 7):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);`

For more info you can refer: [How to start a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request and judge request type in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153650/how-to-start-a-get-post-put-delete-request-and-judge-request-type-in-php)

Comment: We could also use `file_get_contents` with a custom HTTP `stream context`. Check [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2153670/4058484).

Answer (score 0):

1. HTTP `PUT` method is generally used to update resource.
2. First need to bring (`GET`) resource information.
3. and then update resource information according your parameters.
4. Finally, make `PUT` request to server.

In php, curl is used for making rest calls. HTTP `GET` and `POST` are directly supported in curl. But for PUT and DELETE you have to set options accordingly in `curl_setopt()`

```
     $curl = curl_init($url);

     **curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"PUT")**;
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);

     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$update_para);

     $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
```