# sending put request (cURL)

Tags: php, curl, request

hello im trying send PUT request with email information to specified url but im getting an error:

> `"success":false,"error":"The request you sent is either invalid or too big."`

I've seen many tutorials but cant make any of them work. This is code i've been trying:

```
<?php 
$handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array(
    $handle,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.trikoder.hr/api/v1/RequestJobApplication/",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "?email=xxx@gmail.com",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    )
);

$response = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: You'll properly need to specif that you want to do a `PUT` request, I believe in PHP curls are by default `GET`

Comment: +1, CURLOPT_PUT is the thing you are searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just few lines in python, I've checked and it works :)

I da majstore sretno na razgovoru :)

```
 import requests

    r = requests.put("http://www.trikoder.hr/api/v1/RequestJobApplication/", "email=spada4ever@hotmail.com")
    print r.json()
```

Comment: hvala samo nemoj me cinkat :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not in PHP but it's one of the solutions:

`curl -X PUT http://www.trikoder.hr/api/v1/RequestJobApplication/ -d email=bla@smth.com`

Good luck with job interview...

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to try below code. it will showing some response not an error.
 you need to set post fields to true and also curl auto make query string for post fields.
either check your url .
http://www.trikoder.hr/api/v1/RequestJobApplication/

```
$handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array(
    $handle,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.trikoder.hr/api/v1/RequestJobApplication/",
         CURLOPT_POST=> 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "email=xxx@gmail.com",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    )
);

$response = curl_exec($handle);
$output = curl_getinfo($handle);
print_r($output);
curl_close($handle);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
```

i have tried and output of curl info is ok need to check your end and
output is:-

```
Array ( [url] => http://www.trikoder.hr/api/v1/RequestJobApplication/ [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 341 [request_size] => 172 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.904 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0.421 [pretransfer_time] => 0.421 [size_upload] => 19 [size_download] => 132 [speed_download] => 146 [speed_upload] => 21 [download_content_length] => 132 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0.904 [redirect_time] => 0 )
```

for about put request follow :-
[Send PUT request with PHP cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257295/send-put-request-with-php-curl)

Comment: still nothing :/, and my bad in CURLOPT_URL in the end is backslash so: http://www.trikoder.hr/api/v1/RequestJobApplication/

Comment: whit this code i get: {"success":false,"error":"The request you sent is either invalid or too big. You ought to Google how to make a proper PUT request."}

Comment: but curl posting is ok you need to check what you send response on that url back

Comment: maybe i'm missing some key information, here is what task says to do:
"send PUT request which contains email=your_email@xxx.com and get unique URL.

API URL - http://www.trikoder.hr/api/v1/RequestJobApplication/

Comment: now i get :{"success":false,"error":"Your request contains invalid data. Follow the instructions and send raw data."}

Answer (score 0):

You must define the length of content when doing `PUT` otherwise it will not work. Example:

```
$fields = "email=xxx@gmail.com";

CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.trikoder.hr/api/v1/RequestJobApplication/",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
// this is must for PUT
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Length: ' . strlen($fields)),
```

Comment: still same error :/, 
{"success":false,"error":"Your request contains invalid data. Follow the instructions and send raw data."}