# PHP cURL with JSON and raw body

Tags: php, json, curl, postman

I'm trying to connect API with PHP. But all I get is "Command parameters are required". In order to work I need to send RAW Body data with it and it needs to be in PUT method.

Json data needs to look like

```
{
"OutputID":"Some key",
"Activate":true,
}
```

Here is my code

```
    $curl = curl_init($URL);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");  

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$jsonData = array(
    'OutputID' => 'Some key',
    'Activate' => true,
);

$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(   
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: 0',
    $Authorization_Token_Key));


if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
else
{
    echo '';
}
```

If I try it with Postman it works but not in PHP Script.

Comment: Can you expand upon what you mean by it not working in PHP?

Comment: Since you want to use the `PUT` method, I imagine that you should remove `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

Comment: Your `Content-Length` is not 0.

Answer (score 4):

@Patrick

You where right :)

I removed

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

And it works like a charm

Thanks

Comment: Instead try using `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257295/send-put-request-with-php-curl